# AS3 - RGB coloring?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, colors

I am making this game in AS3. It's about a ball and a pad. The user can move the pad to prevent the ball from hitting the floor. Anyways, I want the ball to change color to a randomly generated color. So I have got a mathrandom for every color value, R G B.

```
var r;
var g;
var b;

function getColor(){
    r = Math.round(Math.random()*256);
    g = Math.round(Math.random()*256);
    b = Math.round(Math.random()*256);
}
```

But I don't know how to color the ball with RGB colors. I don't even know if it's possible.

Comment: You wanted to write 255, probably: trace(0xFF.toString()); //traces(255, not 256);

Comment: @Fygo is correct. RGB values are 0-255, not 1-256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var r;
var g;
var b;

function getColor():uint{
    var resultColor:uint;
    r = Math.round(Math.random()*0xFF); //0xFF equivalent to 255 
    g = Math.round(Math.random()*0xFF);
    b = Math.round(Math.random()*0xFF);

    resultColor = r<<16 | g<<8 | b;
    return resultColor;
}
```

The Color is in 0xRRGGBB format in AS3. So we combine the 3 values using bitwise operations.
Hope this might help. Check this for further info : [Bit Operations in AS3](http://www.nicolabortignon.com/as3-bitwise-operations/)

Comment: How to I use that value later on?  mainBall.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform("What should be here?");

Comment: @CarlA
var my_color:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
my_color.color = getColor();
mainBall.transform.colorTransform = my_color;

Check this out [link](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3colortransform/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your implementation.  If you're programmatically creating your ball (such as)...

```
var ball:Shape = new Shape();
ball.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
ball.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
ball.graphics.endFill();
```

... then you could easily draw the updated circle by first calling `ball.clear()` and redrawing it with your new color value.  Be aware that [`beginFill()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginFill%28%29) uses uint values, and you can easily generate these using the same `Math.random()`.  Here's a modified version of your function that allows you to define the low & high values.

```
function randomRange(low:Number=0, high:Number=1):Number {
    /* Returns a random number between the low and high values given. */
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
}
```

... at which point your `beginFill()` would look like this:

```
ball.graphics.beginFill(randomRange(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF);
```

Which effectively retrieves a random color between black and white.

However, if you're modifying an existing image (such as a loaded Bitmap), you want a [`colorTransform()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html).  Here's one for RGB I wrote:

```
tintRGB(target:Object, r:Number, g:Number, b:Number, alpha:Number = 1):void {
    if (target.hasOwnProperty("transform")) {
        target.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,alpha,r,g,b,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got,

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method ColorTransform.

Comment: Likely because you omitted the import?  Try `import flash.geom.ColorTransform;`